# Fine uploader azure blob storage delete file option

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader to upload images to azure blob storage, everything is working and now I want to delete file. I used below code

```
deleteFile: {
    enabled: true,
    endpoint: 'api/documentManager',
    method: 'DELETE'
 }
```

the fie being deleted successfully from blob storage but the callback for sever handling is not getting called. Any thing that I am missing?

Comment: What sort of callback are you expecting, and why?

Comment: I have records of all uploaded files in my database and when some deletes the blob from azure, I want to delete the related entry from the database. I am able to send request to my server from onDeleteComplete callback using  xhr.send();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no server callback when using the delete file feature in fine uploader azure. The request is sent directly to azure. If you would like to contact your server after the delete has completed, do so in the onDeleteComplete callback.

Comment: Is there is way to overwrite the blob? I want to overwrite blob if user uploads the file with name that already exits